# Flutter || How to implement Shared Preferences in webview

Tags: android, flutter, authentication, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I have a WebView project in flutter and I want to add my own page of authentication at first when you open the page I don't know if there is a way the user can authenticate from this page with the cache of my WebView.

Comment: The question is not clear. Please mention more details about how the authentication process works. Also, mention what you have tried and what problems are you facing.